# Problem with tikz: Arrows not parallel

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want all the vertical lines parallel in this example. How can I manage that? Thanks a lot.
Here is a picture.

[image: picture]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=1.5em,
              column sep=1.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex, text centered]
              {
                          & 0 &   & A &       & A\amalg_AB     &       & C     & & 0\\
                        0 &   & A &       & B     &                        & C     &       & 0\\    
                          & 0 &   & A &       & A\amalg_AB &       & C & & 0\\
                    0 &   & A &       & B &                        & C &       & 0\\
              };
              \path[->,font=\scriptsize]

                    (m-2-1) edge node[auto] {} (m-2-3)
                    (m-2-3) edge node[auto] {$f$} (m-2-5)               
                    (m-2-5) edge node[auto] {$g$} (m-2-7)
                    (m-2-7) edge node[auto] {} (m-2-9)

                    (m-4-1) edge node[auto] {} (m-4-3)
                    (m-4-3) edge node[auto] {$f$} (m-4-5)               
                    (m-4-5) edge node[auto] {$g$} (m-4-7)
                    (m-4-7) edge node[auto] {} (m-4-9)

                    (m-1-2) edge node[auto] {} (m-1-4)
                    (m-1-4) edge node[auto] {$$} (m-1-6)                
                    (m-1-6) edge node[auto] {$$} (m-1-8)
                    (m-1-8) edge node[auto] {} (m-1-10)

                    (m-3-2) edge node[auto] {} (m-3-4)
                    (m-3-4) edge node[auto] {$$} (m-3-6)                
                    (m-3-6) edge node[auto] {$$} (m-3-8)
                    (m-3-8) edge node[auto] {} (m-3-10)

                    (m-2-3) edge node[auto] {} (m-1-4)
                    (m-2-5) edge node[auto] {} (m-1-6)
                    (m-2-7) edge node[auto] {} (m-1-8)

                    (m-4-3) edge node[auto] {} (m-3-4)
                    (m-4-5) edge node[auto] {} (m-3-6)
                    (m-4-7) edge node[auto] {} (m-3-8)
                    ;
            \end{tikzpicture}
           \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `text width=1cm` counts?

Comment: Same problem like here: [How to ensure consecutive diagonal arrows form a straight line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89056). The `tikz-cd` package uses a `\matrix` internally. For example, you could use `column sep={between origins,3.5em}` and get parallel arrows, although you have to make sure that the nodes are not overlapping or too narrow.

Comment: Could somebody "translate" me this solution into my example. I am totally no expert I never used "tikzcd", what is used in the solution you mentioned.

Comment: It's easier to type `A'` instead of `A^\prime` or `A^\pr` defining a new command. The result is precisely the same.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But I still didn't solve my actual problem.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I hoped that `column sep={3.5em,between origins}` worked in `tikz-cd`; unfortunately it appears it doesn't.

Comment: @egreg I have re-defined `\tikzcd@sep` (and the `… sep` keys) mainly so that it works with the pre-defined styles `normal`, `small` etc. But the fix also provides a better interface to use `between origins`. Without the fix, you can use `column sep={{{{3.5em,between origins}}}}`; the key value gets handed down three times and is not protected properly.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Your code works, but I get four `\end occurred when \ifx on line XY was incomplete` messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of Qrrbrbirlbel, here's a solution with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand\push[3]{#1\amalg_{#2}#3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={{{{3em,between origins}}}}]%[bo column sep=3em]
{} & 
0 \arrow{rr} &&
A' \arrow{rr} &&
\smash[b]{\push{A'}{A}{B} \arrow{rr}} &&
C \arrow{rr} &&
0
\\
0 \arrow{rr} &&
A \arrow{rr}{f} \arrow{ur} &&
B \arrow{rr}{g} \arrow{ur} &&
C \arrow{rr} \arrow{ur} &&
0
\\
{} & 
0 \arrow{rr} &&
A' \arrow{rr} &&
\smash[b]{\push{A'}{A}{B'}} \arrow{rr} &&
C' \arrow{rr} &&
0
\\
0 \arrow{rr} &&
A \arrow{rr}{f'} \arrow{ur} &&
B' \arrow{rr}{g'} \arrow{ur} &&
C' \arrow{rr} \arrow{ur} &&
0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The only subtle points are

1. `column sep={{{{3em,between origins}}}}` with four pairs of braces.
2. the `\smash[b]{...}` around the push out, in order to get the same length for the middle arrows.

The syntax of `tikz-cd` is surely more friendly. I believe that a bug report to the author of `tikz-cd` in order to fix the `column sep` problem is in order.

[image]

Comment: The bug fix is essentially only `\patchcmd\tikzcd@sep{=#2}{={#2}}{}{}`. Then only one pair of `{ }` is needed (as usual for the `,`). But then one cannot use pre-defined settings like `normal` and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will begin using tikz-cd. I am only interested in drawing diagrams anyway.