# How can I force arrows in tikz-cd to ignor the text on the cell they come from (or go to)?

Tags: tikz-cd

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = tiny]
    {...}  & {-2} & {-1} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  & {...} \\
    {} &&&&&&& {} \\
    {} &&&&&&& {} \\
    {...}  & {-2} & {-1} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  & {...} \\
    \arrow[from=1-4, to=4-8]
    \arrow[from=1-6, to=4-6]
    \arrow[from=1-8, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=4-10]
    \arrow[from=1-10, to=4-2]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

yields the following figure :

[image]

For obvious aesthetic reasons, I would like the figure  the arrows to cross in one central point.
How can I achieve this with tikz-cd ?

Comment: `text width=width("$-0$")` to get the minimal needed width for the nodes (in this simple case) or [using `between origins`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89056) is another way to approach this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the cells that contain a `-` sign are wider than the cells that don't. Since the arrows are drawn to the centers of the cells, they are slightly off center with respect to the rest of the diagram. One solution is to set `minimum width` for every cell. (If you wish you can also reduce `column sep` to 0.)

Also, you only need two rows if you set `row sep`, and the last row should not have `\\` at the end (to have proper vertical spacing after the diagram). Lastly, use `\cdots` instead of `{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0pt, minimum width=8mm, row sep=2cm]
    \cdots & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & \cdots \\
    \cdots & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & \cdots
    \arrow[from=1-4, to=2-8]
    \arrow[from=1-6, to=2-6]
    \arrow[from=1-8, to=2-4]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-10]
    \arrow[from=1-10, to=2-2]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```