# Distorted arrows when scaling tikzcd graph horizontally

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I have a communicative graph in a `tikzcd` environment, here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=5ex, column sep=0.01ex]
                                       &                                  &                         &                                   &                          &                                   &                          &                                   &                                                    & \text{Drop the coins}             &                          &                                              &                          &                                   &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
1^\text{st}\text{ Layer}               &                                  &                         &                                   &                          &                                   &                          &                                   &                                                    & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]           &                          &                                              &                          &                                   &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
2^\text{nd}\text{ Layer}               &                                  &                         &                                   &                          &                                   &                          &                                   & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]                            &                                   & 1 \arrow[rd] \arrow[ld]  &                                              &                          &                                   &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
3^\text{rd}\text{ Layer}               &                                  &                         &                                   &                          &                                   &                          & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]           &                                                    & 2 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]           &                          & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]                      &                          &                                   &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
4^\text{th}\text{ Layer}               &                                  &                         &                                   &                          &                                   & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]  &                                   & 3 \arrow[ld, Rightarrow] \arrow[rd, dashed, hook'] &                                   & 3 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]  &                                              & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]  &                                   &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
5^\text{th}\text{ Layer}               &                                  &                         &                                   &                          & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]           &                          & 7 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]           &                                                    & 3 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]           &                          & 4 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]                      &                          & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]           &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
6^\text{th}\text{ Layer}               &                                  &                         &                                   & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]  &                                   & 8 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]  &                                   & 10 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]                           &                                   & 7 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]  &                                              & 5 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]  &                                   & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd] &                                  &                         &                          \\
7^\text{th}\text{ Layer}               &                                  &                         & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]           &                          & 9 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]           &                          & 18 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]          &                                                    & 17 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]          &                          & 12 \arrow[ld, dashed] \arrow[rd, Rightarrow] &                          & 6 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]           &                         & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]          &                         &                          \\
8^\text{th}\text{ Layer}               &                                  & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd] &                                   & 10 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd] &                                   & 27 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd] &                                   & 35 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd]                           &                                   & 17 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd] &                                              & 30 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd] &                                   & 7 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd] &                                  & 1 \arrow[ld] \arrow[rd] &                          \\
9^\text{th}\text{ Layer}               & 1                                &                         & 11                                &                          & 37                                &                          & 62                                &                                                    & 52                                &                          & 47                                           &                          & 37                                &                         & 8                                &                         & 1                        \\
\text{Outcome}                         & 1^\text{st}\text{ Slot}          &                         & 2^\text{nd}\text{ Slot}           &                          & 3^\text{rd}\text{ Slot}           &                          & 4^\text{th}\text{ Slot}           &                                                    & 5^\text{th}\text{ Slot}           &                          & 6^\text{th}\text{ Slot}                      &                          & 7^\text{th}\text{ Slot}           &                         & 8^\text{th}\text{ Slot}          &                         & 9^\text{th}\text{ Layer} \\
\text{Probability of hitting it once}  & \frac{1}{2^{9-1}}                &                         & \frac{11}{2^{9-1}}                &                          & \frac{37}{2^{9-1}}                &                          & \frac{62}{2^{9-1}}                &                                                    & \frac{52}{2^{9-1}}                &                          & \frac{47}{2^{9-1}}                           &                          & \frac{37}{2^{9-1}}                &                         & \frac{8}{2^{9-1}}                &                         & \frac{1}{2^{9-1}}        \\
\text{Probability of hitting it twice} & \left(\frac{1}{2^{9-1}}\right)^2 &                         & \left(\frac{11}{2^{9-1}}\right)^2 &                          & \left(\frac{37}{2^{9-1}}\right)^2 &                          & \left(\frac{62}{2^{9-1}}\right)^2 &                                                    & \left(\frac{52}{2^{9-1}}\right)^2 &                          & \left(\frac{47}{2^{9-1}}\right)^2            &                          & \left(\frac{37}{2^{9-1}}\right)^2 &                         & \left(\frac{8}{2^{9-1}}\right)^2 &                         & \frac{1}{2^{9-1}}       
\end{tikzcd}
```

However, the output is distorted and does not fit onto the page:

[image]

The diagram I'm trying to draw is here
https://tinyurl.com/znyhpd5c

Comment: Welcome! I'd argue it's not distorted. Every column gets the space the widest node requires. (The same is true for the vertical dimension but less noticeable here.) Try `column sep={2.3em,between origins}, /tikz/column 1/.append style={nodes={anchor=base east}}` as options to your `tikzcd` environment. (The `Drop the coins` node is the doing most damage. You can also add `|[overlay]|` to the this cell only but that still makes the columns of different width. Or you could remove that node from the matrix and add it as a label to the matrix. But I think you should use `between origins` anyway.)

Comment: Related: [Q89056](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89056) and [possibly more](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btikz-cd%5D+between+origins).

Comment: It worked thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `between origins` and some more adjustments.

The following still yields an overfull by 60pt, solving it is up to you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\newcommand{\ly}[2]{\text{#1#2 Layer}}
\newcommand{\st}[2]{\smash{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1#2 \\Slot\end{tabular}}}
\newcommand{\prob}[1]{\smash{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Probability of\\hitting it #1\end{tabular}}}
\newcommand{\pb}[1]{\frac{#1}{2^{9-1}}}
\newcommand{\pbb}[1]{\left(\frac{#1}{2^{9-1}}\right)^{2}}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  row sep=5ex,
  column sep={1.8em,between origins},
  /tikz/column 1/.append style={nodes={anchor=base west}},
]
&[7.5em] &&&&&&&& \makebox[0pt]{Drop the coins} \\[-4ex]
\ly{1}{st}     &            &                   &                   &                    &                                   &                          &                                   &                                                    & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]           &                          &                                              &                          &                                   &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
\ly{2}{nd}     &            &                   &                   &                    &                                   &                          &                                   & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]                            &                                   & 1 \ar[rd] \ar[ld]  &                                              &                          &                                   &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
\ly{3}{rd}     &            &                   &                   &                    &                                   &                          & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]           &                                                    & 2 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]           &                          & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]                      &                          &                                   &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
\ly{4}{th}     &            &                   &                   &                    &                                   & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]  &                                   & 3 \ar[ld, Rightarrow] \ar[rd, dashed, hook'] &                                   & 3 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]  &                                              & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]  &                                   &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
\ly{5}{th}     &            &                   &                   &                    & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]           &                          & 7 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]           &                                                    & 3 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]           &                          & 4 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]                      &                          & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]           &                         &                                  &                         &                          \\
\ly{6}{th}     &            &                   &                   & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]  &                                   & 8 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]  &                                   & 10 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]                           &                                   & 7 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]  &                                              & 5 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]  &                                   & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd] &                                  &                         &                          \\
\ly{7}{th}     &            &                   & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd] &                    & 9 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]           &                          & 18 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]          &                                                    & 17 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]          &                          & 12 \ar[ld, dashed] \ar[rd, Rightarrow] &                          & 6 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]           &                         & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]          &                         &                          \\
\ly{8}{th}     &            & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd] &                   & 10 \ar[ld] \ar[rd] &                                   & 27 \ar[ld] \ar[rd] &                                   & 35 \ar[ld] \ar[rd]                           &                                   & 17 \ar[ld] \ar[rd] &                                              & 30 \ar[ld] \ar[rd] &                                   & 7 \ar[ld] \ar[rd] &                                  & 1 \ar[ld] \ar[rd] &                          \\
\ly{9}{th}     & 1          &                   & 11                &                    & 37                                &                          & 62                                &                                                    & 52                                &                          & 47                                           &                          & 37                                &                         & 8                                &                         & 1                        \\[-3ex]
\text{Outcome} & \st{1}{st} &                   & \st{2}{nd}        &                    & \st{3}{th}          &                          & \st{4}{th}          &                                                    & \st{5}{th}           &                          & \st{6}{th}                      &                          & \st{7}{th}           &                         & \st{8}{th}          &                         & \st{9}{th} \\[-2ex]
\prob{once}    & \pb{1}     &                   & \pb{11}           &                    & \pb{37}                &                          & \pb{62}                &                                                    & \pb{52}                &                          & \pb{47}                          &                          & \pb{37}               &                         & \pb{8}                &                         & \pb{1}        \\[-2ex]
\prob{twice}    & \pbb{1}     &                   & \pbb{11}           &                    & \pbb{37}                &                          & \pbb{62}                &                                                    & \pbb{52}                &                          & \pbb{47}                          &                          & \pbb{37}               &                         & \pbb{8}                &                         & \pbb{1}        \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Note the helper local macros to ease input. You can easily change the position of the ordinal markers (don't use superscripts, please).

[image]